# Declaring an array of buttons before knowing what the size needs to be and define outside the onCreate() method

Tags: java, android, declaration, definition

So I want to dynamically add buttons to my layout in android studio, but I don't know how many buttons I need in the "onCreate" method. So I just declare and define 50 buttons that I later add into the layout.

```
public class ChooseMatchupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //THIS IS PROBLEM #1 RIGHT HERE!!! I DON'T KNOW HOW MANY BUTTONS I CAN HAVE UNTIL AFTER
    // I GET THE NUMBER OF MATCHUPS FOR THE DAY FROM THE API, SO I JUST DECLARE 50
    Button matchupButtons[] = new Button[50];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_matchup);

        String apiFeedUrl = "https://api.somesportssite.com/pull/current/daily_game_schedule.json?fordate=20180113";

        ll = findViewById(R.id.matchup_layout);
        lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //THIS IS PROBLEM #2 RIGHT HERE!!! I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DEFINE ALL OF THE BUTTONS IN THE "RetrieveFeedTask" CLASS
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            matchupButtons[i] = new Button(this);
            matchupButtons[i].setTextSize(30);
            matchupButtons[i].setGravity(Gravity.START);
        }

        // Get data feed from API
        new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(apiFeedUrl);
    }

    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String url = urls[0];
            String response = null;

            URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            response = stringBuilder.toString();
            return response;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            /* Grab all matchups from API and add them to the layout */
            try{

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray games = obj.getJSONObject("dailygameschedule").getJSONArray("gameentry");

                //WOULD LIKE TO DECLARE AND DEFINE ALL BUTTONS RIGHT HERE

                for (int i = 0; i < games.length(); i++){

                    String awayTeam = games.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("awayTeam").getString("Name");
                    String homeTeam = games.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("homeTeam").getString("Name");
                    String matchUpStr = awayTeam + "\n" + homeTeam;

                    matchupButtons[i].setText(matchUpStr);
                    ll.addView(matchupButtons[i], lp);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made comments where I felt the most work was needed. I would like to declare and define all of the buttons in the "onPostExecute" method. Is there a way to do this? I'm starting to think it might be good to make a call to the api first in the "onCreate" method to find out what the size needs to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what size you need your array to be you should use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), it can expand to the required size.

Comment: Your solution worked. Check out the code in my answer. Let me know if there is a way to set the size of the text instead of having to do it every time a new button is created in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ivan Wooll said, since I didn't know what size I needed the array of buttons to be, I should use an ArrayList. I am just going to post the code in case anyone wants to see the solution:
instead of:

```
Button matchupButtons[] = new Button[50];
```

I did:

```
ArrayList<Button> matchupButtons = new ArrayList<>();
```

I took out the for loop in the onCreate method that defined all of the buttons and put it in the onPostExecute method in the RetrieveFeedTask class.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    Log.v(TAG, "HTTP Response: " + response);

    /* Grab all matchups from API and add them to the layout */
    try{

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray games = obj.getJSONObject("dailygameschedule").getJSONArray("gameentry");

        for (int i = 0; i < games.length(); i++){

            Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            button.setTextSize(30);
            button.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            matchupButtons.add(button);

            String awayTeam = games.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("awayTeam").getString("Name");
            String homeTeam = games.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("homeTeam").getString("Name");
            String matchUpStr = awayTeam + "\n" + homeTeam;

            matchupButtons.get(i).setText(matchUpStr);
            ll.addView( matchupButtons.get(i), lp);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I would now like to set the text size and gravity for all of the buttons in the ArrayList instead of having to set it every time a new button is created in the for loop as shown above. Let me know if there is a way to set that. Thanks!